# PHP Function name needs to be a string

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, security

I'm trying to make an incredibly basic php form that outputs some text a user puts in to a database. Looked at a couple other questions like this to make sure and from what I can tell no one else asked about this. Here's the create.php that takes input from the html.

```
<?php 
    include 'connection.php';  
    $firstname= $_POST('inputName'); 
    $lastname= $_POST('inputName2');
    if($_POST ['SUBMIT']) { echo "please fill out the form"; 
    header('location:     ../index.html'); 
    } else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO requestdata ('firstname', 'lastname') 
    VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname')") or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo "User has been added"; header ('Location: ../index.html'); 
    } 
    ?>
```

Here's the html code for the form:

```
<form action = "php/create.php" method = "POST">
    First Name <input type ="text" name='inputName' value=""/>
    Last Name <input type="text" name='inputName2' value=""/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name = "button">
</form>`
```

and the error I'm getting is:

> "Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   mywebsite.com/php/create.php on line 8

Comment: $_POST is an array try with [] instead of ().

Comment: Do not output anything before `header()`. Read the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think your $_POST variables are wrong.

Please try $_POST['inputName'] instead of $_POST('inputName') and $_POST['inputName2'] instead of $_POST('inputName2')

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Now i have a different error but I think I can deal with this one.